# next.js: useEffect triggered twice when using param from router

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have this code

```
const router = useRouter();
const { pid } = router.query;

useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('my/endpoint/' + pid)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
                setLoading(false)
            })
    }, [pid]);
```

I can see from the browser console a call to the api with pid = undefined, and right after another call with the actual pid value. How can I avoid the first call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirty and fast solution, just controll if `pid` is defined

```
const router = useRouter();
const { pid } = router.query;

useEffect(() => {
     if(pid) {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('my/endpoint/' + pid)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
                setLoading(false)
            })
       }
    }, [pid]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
useEffect(() => {
     if(pid) { // will run if pid is valid
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('my/endpoint/' + pid)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
                setLoading(false)
            })
       }
    }, [pid]);
```